# PHP, едит поста в модальном окне bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript

id поста у меня передается таким образом:

```
 <a id="edit_a" href="http://kurusa.zhecky.net/lesson_16/html_post.php
 ?id_edit=<?=$row['post_id']?>" Править </a>
```

А модальное окно, где должен отобразиться текст поста (что я вытянула запросом по id) открывается вот так:

```
$("#edit_a").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal({show: true});
    });
```

И обращаюсь к вам с несколькими "но":

1). Модальное окно показывается, но, само собой, страница перезагружается и оно исчезает. Не могу с этим разобраться. Как я понимаю, надо использовать header. И, кстати, если модалку закрыть в php if-e, оно не открывается :С А так было бы намного проще. С этого второе но:

2). Как, в конце концов, отобразить этот текст в модалке? Т.е. можно сделать вот так:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
   <input name="input">
   <button type="submit" name="submit"></button>
 </form>

 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
       <p> <?php echo $_POST['input'];?></p>
 <?php } ?>
```

Но с модальным окном так не выходит. Это, выходит, только с помощью javascipt это можно сделать?

Спасибо за внимание тем, кто дочитал :з

Comment: То есть вам нужно сделать вывод текста по id в модальное окно при клике на ссылку?  Ajax js jquery

Comment: @Даниил, да, моя идея именно такова. Но с  Ajax еще не знакома :с

Comment: @Даниил, вы имеете ввиду вот так? `*много-много дивов*<p><?=$_GET['post_text']?></p` и `$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#myModal").modal({show: true}); });`. Но я точно что-то упустила

Comment: @Даниил, но тогда еще вопросы: уже в третий раз слышу, что надо использовать $(document).ready, но ведь тогда модальное окно открывается сразу при загрузке. Чего я не понимаю? И ещё просто так не напишешь `<p><?=$_GET['post_text']?></p>`, ведь ошибка. Возможно, я не учла 'вызывайте форму модульную при загрузки страницы'. Где здесь подвох? :с

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставляйте вывод контента в тело модального окна `<?php echo $_GET['content']; ?>`, и вызывайте окно по условию.

```
<?php if (isseet($_GET['id_edit'])) {?> 
  <script> 
     $("#myModal").modal({ show:true });
  </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно такого рода получится запись:

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        echo "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>'";
        echo '<script> $(document).ready(function () { $("#myModal").modal({show: true}); }); </script>';
    ?>
       <p> <?php echo $_POST['input'];?></p>
 <?php } ?>
```

На случай если скрипт располагается в конце страницы вывод подключения JQuery можно удалить (Только если он был подключен ранее само собой).

Comment: не особо получается. В результате, при загрузке страницы, у меня показывается пустая модалка и в левом верхнем углу id (но оно не столь важно, запросы писать уже умею). А если написать `$("#edit").click(function ()`, то вообще ничего не происходит :с